# WCF Authentication Strategies

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, rest, soap

I have been challenged with the task of coming up with an authentication/authorization strategy for a pretty big WCF API. My task is to implement security on this API from clients who might be a website, a mobile app, or an internal/network admin user (which is pretty much the goal of any solid API).

I have looked into Windows Identity Foundation and federated security, but it relies on WS-* and my clients might be using REST or a non-SOAP protocol. So, my question:

**Is there a security strategy (per method call, preferably using attributes) for WCF that does not rely on SOAP or involve reams of configuration files?**

I realize there's probably no catch-all solution. I'm really looking for ideas or suggestions. This turns out to be a really tricky challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Authentication and HTTPS is a straightforward and "secure enough" solution for most API **authentication** requirements.

When you say "per method call", I'm getting the impression that are talking about **authorization**. For that you are probably going to have to roll something yourself.  The upcoming [Microsoft Web Api framework](http://wcf.codeplex.com) has some good extension points that will make this type of functionality much easier to implement.  It shouldn't be too long before someone implements a reusable module for this framework that you can just plug in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep my eye out for that. Sounds promising.